# python: how to reduce to one-liner:

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How do I write the following in minimum lines?

```
if a in dict:
   if b in dict[a]:
       if c in dict[a][b]:
            if d in dict[a][b][c]:
                 print("Value = ", dict[a][b][c][d])
```

Using python 3.10

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use a `try/except` block instead of checking if each key is present. In your case I would go for:

```
try:
    print("Value = ", dict[a][b][c][d])
except KeyError as e:
    print(f"Missing key: {e}")
```

Comment: Why is it best practice?
I have cases that the keys don't exist on purpose...

I thought that catching exceptions are only for finishing the program and getting error messages

Comment: This article explains why this approach is preferred: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/